# How do I find $P(X\le Y)$?

Tags: probability

I am studying for my exam in probability and I am trying to calculate $P(X \leq Y)$.

I know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and that $X \sim \text{Exp}(1)$ and $Y \sim \text{Exp}(2)$.

I thought that I should use double integral but I cant make it work. I know the answer is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The joint distribution density $f(x,y)$ for $(X,Y)$ is the product of the distribution densities of $X$ ($f_X(x)=e^{-x}$) and $Y$ ($f_Y(y)=2e^{-2y}$) (by independence) and the probability asked for is, as usual:

$$\int_{A} f_X(x)f_Y(y)\,dxdy \text{ with } A=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: 0 \le x \le y\}$$

and we can write this as a double integral if we realise that $x$ can run from $0$ to $+\infty$ and $y$ runs (for fixed $x$) from $x$ to $\infty$), so:

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \left( \int_x^{+\infty} 2e^{-2y}dy \right) e^{-x}dx$$

which should be easily computable... (and $\frac13$ checks out).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: if you set $Z:=(X,Y)$ then $\Pr[X\leqslant Y]=\Pr[Z\in A]$ for $A:=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R ^2:x\leqslant y\}$.

Comment: By Z do you mean the joint PDF for X,Y? If yes how do we calcuate $P(Z \in A)$? If I were supposed to find  $P(x < \frac{1}{2})$ I would just find the integral $\int_0^{1/2} f_X(x)dx$. Thanks.

Comment: @MathiasNissen Just integrate the PDF over $A$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(Y\ge X) = P(Y-X\ge0)$

Put $Z = Y-X$

Then $$P(Z\ge z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\int_{z+x}^{\infty} 2.e^{-2y}dydx$$

$$P(Z\ge z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\left(e^{-2(z+x)}\right)dx$$

$$P(Z\ge z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2z}\left(e^{-3x}\right)dx$$

$$P(Z\ge z) =\frac{1}{3}e^{-2z}$$

$$P(Z\ge 0) = \frac{1}{3}$$